# How to Make a CRUD with Relationship between more than 1 Table - GroceryCRUD

Tags: crud, grocery-crud

I have a simple question here regarding GroceryCRUD.

The question is: Is there a way to build a CRUD using Grocery when I have multiple relationship (JOINs)? For example: I want to have a CRUD for the following:

**Table QUESTIONS** 
IDQuestion 
IDRightAnswer 
IDKnowledgeArea 
Question 
IDExplanation

One Record in this table would contain: 
IDQuestion IDRightAnswer IDKnowledgeArea Question 
10---------------2----------------------**3**---------------------------What is the color of the sun?

Table KnowledgeArea 
**ID**------------**Name**
1--------------Phisics
2--------------Math
**3**--------------**Astronomy**

So, as this is normalized table, for those IDs (except for IDQuestion cuz it is PK and IDRightAnswer cuz its a FK) which is/are FK in the Questions table, I would like to have the correlated values (text) from Original table displayed in the grid rather than the ID itself.

So, using the same example, for the column **IDKnowledgeArea** in the table Questions (its a FK here) the CRUD would bring a combobox with the original values (text) in the table **IDKnowledgeArea** then I could chose it from there.

For example:

**IDQuestion** **IDRightAnswer** **IDKnowledgeArea**    **Question**
10---------------2-----------------------**Astronomy**-------------What is the color of the sun?

All the CRUD tools I've seen doens't have such resource and although they provide good CRUD approach they never address this multi-relationship between the entities.

I appreciate any answer.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually I gave a look on the documentation and I found this:

http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation

Set a relation 1-n database relation. This will automatically create a dropdown list to the fields and show the actual name of the field and not just a primary key to the list. An example of this:

$crud->set_relation('user_id','users','username');

Thank you all